# Ng-click error (Angular dart)

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

Im new with this language and this framework, Ive made a command-line app and it works perfectly and now I wanna make a very simple web interface

I have this in my .html

```
<body ng-app>
.
.
.
<input type="submit" ng-click="doSomething()">
```

In my .dart

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';
.
.
.
void doSomething(){
lotToDo;
}
```

And I get this

```
Property 'doSomething' is not of type function.
```

Whats the point of the error ? Its necesary to use a controller ?

Thanks to all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a controller that contains the `doSomething()` method.

See https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_03/lib/recipe_book.dart for example.

The `index.html` has a tag `<body recipe-book>` tag. Angular applies the controller declared in `recipe_book.dart` here because this controller has the selector `selector: '[recipe-book]'` assigned which is a tag that has the attribute `recipe-book`.

You also need to initialize a module so Angular knows of this controller.

```dart
library recipe_book;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

import 'package:angular_dart_demo/rating/rating_component.dart';
import 'package:angular_dart_demo/recipe_book.dart';

class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(RecipeBookController); // register controller in a module
    type(RatingComponent);      // register some other component
  }
}

void main() {
  applicationFactory()
      .addModule(new MyAppModule()) // tell angular to use the modul declared above
      .run();
}
```

My advice: work through this tutorial before trying random things https://angulardart.org/tutorial/

Comment: With controllers works perfectly but i was looking for something simple.

I just need to get used to this language.

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I think this is as simple as it gets with Angular.